# Multiline textarea value: line feed not present in all lines

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I found a weird bug (?) with textareas...

Say, there's a `<textarea>` with **multiline** text (user-pasted text or pre-set text doesn't matter, tested with both).

I want to get the text from `<textarea>` and replace `\n` with something else... Turns out, the `.replace` works only in the first line.

Here's the code, see what I mean:

```
<textarea id="txt">line1
line2
line3
line4</textarea>

<script>
var strval = document.getElementById("txt").value.replace("\n", "<br>");
// strval returns this:

// line1<br>line2
// line3
// line4
</script>
```

I tested this with Chrome and Firefox. Here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aapgejvb/

Weird huh? Have I just discovered a bug in WebKit or am I stupid?

PS. Tested with jQuery's `.val()` too, same result (obviously)

PPS. Found [this](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-textarea-element.html#concept-textarea-api-value), doesn't help much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.replace("\n", "<br>")` will only replace first occurence of `\n` (newline).
To replace all you should use `replace(/\n/g, "<br />");`

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/aapgejvb/2/

Comment: So it is "I'm stupid" then. Spent too much time C#-ing. Sorry about wasting everyon'es time. Accepting your answer in 5 mins